# How to have two GPUs (RX 5700 XT & RX 580) recognized by Blender simultaneously

Tags: gpu

I'm struggling to get both of my GPUs to be recognized by Blender at the same time. They seem to require different ICDs to function:

RX 5700 XT: `opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd` (`--opencl=pal` from the AMD proprietary driver)

RX 580: `opencl-orca-amdgpu-pro-icd` (`--opencl=legacy` from the AMD proprietary driver)

However installing from the installer results in an error building `amdgpu-dkms` and therefore for this particular setup, skipping `amdgpu-dkms` and installing the packages manually gets *either* one of the GPUs working inside blender, never both even if I install both ICDs.

**System Information**

Operating system: Linux-5.3.0-20-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-19.10-eoan 64 Bits
Graphics card: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT (NAVI10, DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-20-generic, LLVM 9.0.0) X.Org 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.1

**Blender Version**

2.81 (sub 16), branch: master, commit date: 2019-10-28 17:50, hash: rB43a8fdb6addf

Comment: I'm assuming you did this right? If so I'll tell a friend who knows more about multiple GPUs in blender.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoPAF.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoPAF.jpg) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoCcV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoCcV.jpg)

Comment: Yes, getting them seen by blender at the same time is the problem.